# upowerd: "energy_full is greater than energy_full_design" - causes laptop to suspend prematurely (Lenovo Thinkpad T440P)

Tags: gnome, suspend, power-management, battery, thinkpad

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS x86_64 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p. The laptop only runs for about 20 minutes on battery power. In the process of troubleshooting this issue, I have installed tlp and powertop. The output of tlp-stat tipped me off to the fact that the upower daemon is reporting "energy_full" as being greater than "energy_full_design." This is confirmed by running "systemctl status upower" - I get the following:

"Jul 06 23:21:06 cannon upowerd[2055]: energy_full (71.280000) is greater than energy_full_design (47.520000)"

Apparently this is a known bug (see below links) that causes the battery percentage to be inaccurately reported to the OS, causing a premature suspend, but I can't seem to find a fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/583271
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92547

I have stopped and started the upower daemon, and rebooted the machine to no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This bug effectively makes my laptop a desktop.

Comment: I think your conclusion is wrong. What `tlp-stat -b` shows are the values sent by the battery controller to the kernel via ACPI-BIOS. upowerd also reads those sysfiles. It isn't unusual for fresh batteries that `energy_full` is a few % higher than `energy_full_design`. The big discrepancy in your case points to a defective battery controller (the one inside the battery pack). I suggest to replace the battery.

Comment: Thanks! I will give that a go. I just ordered a replacement (genuine Lenovo because I read some reports that aftermarket batteries often aren't recognized by the bios and/or lack driver support or something like that?) but it will be weeks before it gets in from Taiwan unfortunately. Again, thanks for the response, I will report back.

Answer (score 0):

the reply from [linrunner](https://askubuntu.com/users/346276/linrunner) was correct. This was due to a faulty battery.